# How to sync an accordion with a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am using two Owl Carousels that are sync'd together to have one main image and thumbnails below. I am using the code from this [pen](https://codepen.io/washaweb/pen/KVRxRW).

I also have an accordion on the page. I need to now sync my accordion with the thumbnails and have them work both ways where if I click on an accordion the thumbnail becomes active and if I click on the thumbnail the accordion opens up.

I have a demo [here](http://ankitdesigns.com/demo/gsid/our-products/sample-product/).

I have added selectors onto both:

**Thumbnail Owl Carousel**

```
$i = 1;

$html_out .= '<div class="item thumb" data-flavor="' . $i++ . '">';
   $html_out .= '<img class="slide-img-thumb" src="' . $slide . '" style="background: no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;" />';
$html_out .= '</div>';
```

**Accordion**

```
$i = 1;
$html .= '<div class="x-accordion-heading">';
    html .= '<a class="x-accordion-toggle collapsed hvr-bounce-to-right" data-flavor="' . $i++ . '" data-cs-collapse-toggle="" data-cs-collapse-parent="#flavour-accordion">' . $title . '</a>';
$html .= '</div>';
```

The main takeaway from each thing is that they both have `data-flavor='1'` and that increments to 2, 3, 4, etc.

How can I properly sync the two?

Comment: Hi, I was looking into your code, why have you removed flavor reference from thumbnai

Comment: @DASH `data-flavor=""` is there now. I am not sure what selectors to make. Before the thumbnails had `data-hash` and the accordion had a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#sync1").on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
 //Added the timeout so that transition completes in that time
 setTimeout(function(){
    var cEl = jQuery("#sync2 .owl-item.active.current");
    var item = cEl.children('.item');
    var flavor = Number(item.data('flavor'));    
    if(!isNaN(flavor)){
        var el = jQuery("[data-cs-collapse-toggle]").filter("[data-flavor='" + flavor + "']");
        if(el.length > 0){
            el.trigger('click');
        }           
    }
}, 100);
})
```

Comment: This feels close, `data-flavor="1"` is opening up the accordion with `data-flavor="4"`. None of the accordions make the thumbs active though.

Comment: can you put the body of the funciton in a timeout of 100 ms, like i did in the answer

Comment: There's an error somewhere, console said syntax error.

Comment: Hi, my bad, there was error in the code, take the current code

Comment: This is really close, however, how do I make the opposite work? Like when I click on the accordion I need the thumbnails to be active too. Also, how can I make it so if a thumbnail doesn't have `data-flavor` to close any accordions?